# Maximum dataset size for a well-performing SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

We're planning a project using SQL Server 2012 for storing about a billion records over less than 50 fields. Assuming good hardware, is SQL Server up to that task?  Roughly how many request/second can I expect to serve using it?

For the project to succeed, SQL Server would have to be able to handle at least 1 read/write request per second.

Comment: Any rdbms is up to the task. But is your hardware? What are your data access patterns? What is your workload? Concurrency?

Comment: @EdwardDortland: hardware is a high-end Xeon blade server. Can obtain more details if required. Workload is pretty mild: no more than 1 query/sec, either read or write. We don't expect many queries to chronologically overlap, at most 2-3 may overlap occasionally.

Comment: The database is up to the task. Are your database developers, architects and administrators equally suited?

Comment: SQL Server is a tool. You will need to know the nuances and intricacies of the tool. You will need to know how to properly ***use*** the tool. I can tell you that I get much better performance than 1 IOPS with many more rows than you're proposing.

Comment: @swasheck, thanks, that's pretty much what I needed to know. Our team prefers SQLServer, so we'll probably go with that. I just needed to ensure it can handle the load, and your reply established that it can. Thanks!

Comment: Even with "bad" hardware and a billion rows, SQL server can still handle 1 read/write request per second (once the caches are warm anyway).  Presumably your peaks are going to be a lot more than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is realistically going to depend on a large number of factors that aren't mentioned here and would probably require more analysis than is realistic in this sort of a forum.

First off, "good hardware" means very different things to different people.  You'd need to analyze how much data needs to be read, how much needs to be written, and what sort of bandwidth your disk subsystem provides.  A RAID-5 array of a few disks in a mid-level server will obviously have very different characteristics than a machine that has hundreds of GB of solid-state disk backed by a high-end SAN with tons of cache where you're spreading the I/O across hundreds of spindles.  A "read request" that fetches a single row will obviously produce very different load than would a "read request" that asks for all 1 billion rows.

Second, the design of your application will be terribly important.  Do all of your reads need to lock the row, for example?  Or is this a data warehouse where you can use a `WITH NOLOCK` on all your queries to potentially allow dirty reads because you won't be running loads at the same time you're running queries?  Will your read requests be for different rows or will large numbers of users be hitting the same set of "hot" rows over and over?

In order to make any sort of reasonable projection, you'd need someone that understood exactly what your application was going to need to do, the physical data model that you'd implement, how SQL Server 2012 operates, and how your specific hardware would behave in various situations.  That's probably outside the scope of this sort of forum-- it's more likely that it is something that you'd a consultant to come in and help with (your hardware vendor may be happy to provide a pre-sales resource to help you size an appropriate server for the task).

Comment: Thanks, Justin. We do plan to get a consultant to look at this question in detail, for now we're in preliminary assessment of whether SQLServer is even the right product, or we should go with something else. That decision must come first since we shouldn't hire a SQLServer specialist if we are better off with a different system. Would love to hear your thoughts about what kind of system that would be; we do have a preference for free/open source software if possible.

Comment: @Dun getting some expert opinion should come first in my opinion: any database professional worth their salt would be able to look into your requirements and give you some general recommendations *before* you commit to an RDBMS.